# 2 3/4" x 1 1/8" board?

Tags: wood, wood-repair, lumber

Lumber question for any professional homeowners / handyfolks out there:

[image: non-standard piece of lumber]

I'm replacing a piece of rotted wood on each side of my garage door frame (piece circled in the image). The actual dimensions of the board are 2 3/4" x 1 1/8" .... anyone know what manner of sorcery are those dimensions? None I'm familiar with (nor is Home Depot or Lowe's).

Maybe those are just boards that were custom-cut to get them flush with the siding? In which case I suppose I'd need to get some at a lumber yard?

Comment: You will need to contact local wood suppliers to find out offered services. Many will not cut custom width or thickness for one piece of softwood! Like garage maybe there is 1 hour minimum charge so board ends up 2X or 3X price :( What tools do you own?

Comment: Were you planning on scarfing in patches or replacing the whole boards? If the plan is to replace the whole boards does the frame have mitred corners or is there a 90° butt joint with the header piece? Do you know what kind of wood you want yet?

Comment: I just went to double check and if this piece is hardwood the size *is* a standard because hardwood is sold differently to construction softwood. Although it's impossible to see what this was originally and softwood IS most likely, if it is hardwood, 5/4 or five quarter is nominally 1 1/4" thick but if it's S1S (smooth one side) it's actually 1 1/8", and S2S would actually be 1 1/16" because some was taken off both faces. So if you bought e.g. 5/4 S1S white oak you'd only need to worry about cutting or planing to width, then whatever end cut is needed [contd]

Comment: White oak is the most common rot-resistant hardwood species in most parts of the US and exterior durability *without finish* is very good. Well primed and painted the replacement will easily outlast you.

Answer (score 3):

That is not an "off the shelf" board. Most likely you'll need a buddy with a table saw to cut wood from the BigBox store to the needed dimensions.

You might be able to contact a local lumber dealer and have them cut some boards to size too. There will be a modest charge and lead time.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of trim shapes like "brick mold". What is worse they change from time to time and different suppliers use different shapes. So it is unlikely you can find a match. An experienced carpenter that is about to repair my similar damage said the whole section should be replaced. I have made a similar repair; I custom made a section using a joiner/planer.  It took time  but the labor was cheap.